# Why is my download link requiring control click to download?

Tags: node.js, html

I am running a pretty basic node.js server to host a site, and all of a sudden this week one of my download links started to just redirect to the index.html page instead of downloading the pdf it points to if you just click on the file. a control+click will download the file, but that is not normal behavior from what I understand with chrome.

The button is generated as so:

```
<button type="button" name="button">
    <a href="../images/a-manill-resume.pdf" download>Downloadable Resume</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Try setting the download attribute

```
<button type="button" name="button"><a download="../images/a-manill-resume.pdf">Downloadable Resume</a></button>
```